# How does a browser include a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, firefox

When you add a `script` tag with an src field pointing to a javascript file, the browser gets it and executes it.

What I am wondering is how does this process work. Does the file get fetched and then somehow `eval()`'ed? Is it a mystical process that happens outside of the scope we have access? Or can we monitor/interfere this?

To explain what I want to achieve:
I want to give access to third parties to customize their page on my site by linking to their own javascript files. I want to be able to centrally log any errors that prevent those external scripts from loading (i.e. their server is down, parsing errors, whatever). Is it possible?

Thanks!

- Obviously there are other ways to solve this such as hosting their scripts on my server and giving them a way to update them, but I 'm interested in knowing if my current approach is possible.

Comment: Greasemonkey is Javascript and runs inside the chrome (sorta, I think). It's possible, you just need to look into probably how add-ons work.

Comment: You might take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450755/save-source-of-popup-window-as-string/12454721#12454721 At least there's a few resources for you to look at. You can see a lot in Firefox and Chrome just by right-clicking and digging around the Console/Inspectors and whatnot.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Thanks but theses are for extensions and extensions are allowed to do things "normal" javascript can't do/access.

Comment: In that context, I was talking about Extensions and other ways of running code on the browser. If you want to see how a browser might request, receive, load and parse, you might be surprised at some of those `view-source:chrome://` files. Take a look at this file in Chrome: **`view-source:chrome://resources/js/util.js`** Copy and paste that into the address bar. You're looking at the Chromium Javascript "source". Wacky.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Ah, I see what you mean now, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Yeah, that answer was where I cataloged what I figured out exploring around. I never had any idea. Try this: **`view-source:chrome://sync-internals/`** Starting on `line 123` (at least on mine), check out that list of internal resources and other browser scripts.

Comment: You have to be a little tricky sometimes too (like figuring out how to get Firefox to open jar files in the browser through the address bar). With the last `view-source` I provided, I have to right-click and open in a new tab; clicking on the source uri does not open the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at specific implementation in Firefox & Chromium sources with some grep magic, for your specific scenario I'd asynchronously subload those by inserting script tags on the fly and listening to global errors/events (eg window.onerror) from there.

Answer (score 0):

It loads the java script file while loading the page and stores that script in its cache. If you load page another time then it will get that js from the cache.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer the question of how to get the error though ;)