# Are there any native methods to triangulate ordered list of points exposed in the browser?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, webgl

I've been dabbling in WebGL over the past few months. [WebGL Fundamentals](http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-fundamentals/) by greggman goes through step-by-step in creating a familiar pixel space. `(0, 0)` is the upper-lefthand corner, matrices enable scale, rotation, and translation, etc.. One thing this got me thinking about is creating more two-dimensional [simple polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon) in the gl context—not too disimilar from `canvas2d` or `svg`.

In order to do this I've pulled together various resources online to triangulate an array of points to be rendered in the browser. The array of points goes through:

1. **Catmull Rom Curve Calculation** takes the array of points and adds handle coordinates `u, v` properties to each point.
2. **Adaptive Subdivision** to break the curve into straight line segments while still appearing curved to the naked eye.
3. **Line Segment Intersection** to check and separate a shape with loops into separate simple polygons.
4. **Tessellation** is finally applied to each of the separated shapes. A final array of triangles is returned to be rendered by WebGL.

### A working example of these operations can be found [here](http://jonobr1.github.com/two.js/tests/webgl-shapes.html). (Requires WebGL enabled browser)

### And the same example in [`svg`](http://jonobr1.github.com/two.js/tests/svg-shapes.html) and [`canvas2d`](http://jonobr1.github.com/two.js/tests/canvas-shapes.html).

Now this is all happening in JavaScript and I agree with what you're thinking, *"This looks and sounds really expensive."* So much so that when changing the vertices on an update loop like `requestAnimationFrame` it runs much slower than `canvas2d` or `svg`. This in part has to do with my ability to transcribe efficient algorithms. But, it must have to do with browser vendors' ability to create affordances and performance increases by writing a similar set of algorithms that I've outlined at a lower level.

So my question is: **Are there any methods the browser vendors use for rendering `canvas2d` and `svg` exposed for developers to use as well?**

*It may sound naïve and that's probably because it is. But hear me out, if WebGL is to be an example api of more native access and control for web developers, why aren't some of the other methods that go hand-in-hand with it available?*

Comment: I thought it was because at least `canvas` is [hardware accelerated](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/02/gpu-accelerating-2d-canvas-and-enabling.html). Also, you can peak behind the scenes in Firefox and Chrome rather easily without ever leaving your browser chrome. See my [pseudo-clackers guide to twiddling into the source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450755/save-source-of-popup-window-as-string/12454721#12454721).

Comment: You can get a lot more speed out of JavaScript if you stick to TypedArrays and try to avoid allocations. I see a lot of `var foo = [x, y, z]` in your code. Every one of those is an allocation, creating a new array object. Eventually you have to copy that data into a typed array in order to load it into WebGL. Better if possible to keep it in a typed array in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. @JaredFarrish, I hadn't known that—I'll take a look under the hood. @gman you're right, I need to make my object / array creation consistent. I thought I had read on [TojiCode](http://blog.tojicode.com) that the construction of new  `Float32Array`'s was really expensive. I'll check out moving everything to TypedArrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in convex polygons only, a simple `TRIANGLE_FAN` in WebGL will suffice.  If you want to draw a concave polygon, you can use a [stencil buffer trick](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html#name13) in WebGL.  But, the answer to your one-sentence question title is "no".

Sometimes JavaScript can be surprisingly fast.  For example, there's a polygon tessellation algorithm that can handle concave polys [here](http://github.prideout.net/polygon.js/) and it runs at interactive rates.

Comment: I hadn't seen that library before. Thanks! I've been using [poly2tri](http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/), which I think may be overkill as it's a pretty big c++ library that's been compiled to JavaScript.