# Placeholder Text

Tags: html, css

Can we change the text content of a `HTML5` **placeholder** using only **CSS** ?

I tried using the `content : ''` but it does not seem to help.

```
<input type="text" class="zip" placeholder="Enter Zip" />

input{
    &:placeholder{
       content:'Search by name'
    }
}
```

Comment: You can work it to a degree. I've got something to work in Chrome so far. Give me a minute.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Could you ping me when you finish? I'd like to see it. I can think of a couple ways to sort of do it but they are all impractical/stupid.

Comment: Example of stupid impractical hack that doesn't work very well: http://jsfiddle.net/6UqQN/

Comment: @WesleyMurch - Oh yeah, this is trying to hack Firefox's innards, plug `resource://gre-resources/forms.css` in Firefox and look for the `::-moz-placehoder` pseudo-element. Unfortunately, you can't access `:before` or `:after`, so `:content` doesn't look exposed here. Now... [*in Chrome*](http://jsfiddle.net/LDkjW/) ... What have I done? `:o` So it's fairly easy in Chrome, just set the pseudo-element's `font-size` to 0, *give* a `font-size` to `:before` and/or `:after`, and voila. Also, using `white-space: pre`, you can nudge that line out of sight too and pair with `:before/:after` as well.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I think that comment is answer-worthy and quite valuable even if it isn't perfection. Ping me if you do and you have my vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following *pseudo-elements* (note the terminology) in webkit-based, Firefox and IE browsers of later vintage:

```
// Note two colons, -input-
::-webkit-input-placeholder

// Note two colons, NO -input-
::-moz-placeholder

// Note ONE colon, -input-
:-ms-input-placeholder
```

This particular "functionality" associated with this one attribute seems to be evolving, so this answer may eventually become dated. These are vendor-prefixed, after all.

What I did find is in webkit-based browsers, you can treat this attribute as a *pseudo-element* (more below on that), to the point you can manipulate it's CSS `content` with `:before` and `:after` in such a way that it *appears* you've changed the `placeholder`. With Firefox, at least right now, that's not possible (also more later). With IE9 (the only version I tested), it did not appear to work.

The following works only in Chrome:

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" class="before" placeholder="Wide "/><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Wide "/><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Wide "/>
```

**CSS**

```
.before::-webkit-input-placeholder:before {
    content: 'Hello \A';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder:before {
    content: 'Hello ';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    white-space: pre;
    font-size: 5px;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {
    content: 'World';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LDkjW/

Note there's two `:before`s in there, showing two methods, one with the `\A` newline which works in CSS, and also a bracketed `:before` and `:after` if you're interested. As you can agree, the `:after` isn't very useful if you've used `\A` with `:before`.

Note, browsers freak out if you have a pseudo-selector it doesn't recognize, so if you decide to include the others, you should do each vendor's in it's own block. In addition, you'll see the lack of `-input-` on the `-moz` (Firefox) pseudo-element. That's because (ta-da) `textarea`'s also get the `placeholder` treatment. And at least Chrome (IE?) does also apply this to `textarea`s. Why `-input-` is in there, who knows.

That's it. I don't know how this is intended to be used, but I suspect it's probably best done another way. If webkit browsers are all you care about, you're good. Otherwise, maybe one day... The rest is just excessive.

---

**Firefox**

You *can* "remove from view" the `placeholder` fairly easily in Firefox:

```
::-moz-placeholder {
    font-size: 0;
    left-indent: -1000px;
    font-color: white;
}
```

You get the idea. `::-moz-placeholder` was `:-moz-placeholder` until recently, which it was given the new selector moniker. Let's take a closer look.

```
:-moz-placeholder  // Legacy
::-moz-placeholder // As of FF17
```

One `:` indicates by convention that this references a *state* of the selected element. Your `hover`s, `:link`, `visited`, `:focused`, as well as the more useful CSS3 pseudo-selectors such as `:nth-child`, `:selected`, `:checked`, etc.

This `::-moz-placeholder` being a *pseudo-element*, it's not observing a state or condition of an element, it's representing an element. A *pseudo* element. Where are we headed with this, you might be thinking.

From what it appears to be, an `input` is not what it appears to be. For instance:

http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/layout/style/forms.css.html

Which you can access through Firefox's address bar using:

*resource://gre-resources/forms.css*

We find things like:

```
input > .anonymous-div,
input::-moz-placeholder {
  word-wrap: normal !important;
  /* Make the line-height equal to the available height */
  line-height: -moz-block-height;
}
```

And:

```
textarea > .anonymous-div,
input > .anonymous-div,
input::-moz-placeholder,
textarea::-moz-placeholder {
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: auto;
   ...
  -moz-text-decoration-color: inherit;
  -moz-text-decoration-style: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  ime-mode: inherit;
  resize: inherit;
}
textarea > .anonymous-div.wrap,
input > .anonymous-div.wrap {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
textarea > .anonymous-div.inherit-overflow,
input > .anonymous-div.inherit-overflow {
  overflow: inherit;
}
input::-moz-placeholder,
textarea::-moz-placeholder {
  /*
   * Changing display to inline can leads to broken behaviour and will assert.
   */
  display: inline-block !important;
  /*
   * Changing resize would display a broken behaviour and will assert.
   */
  resize: none !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  /*
   * The placeholder should be ignored by pointer otherwise, we might have some
   * unexpected behavior like the resize handle not being selectable.
   */
  pointer-events: none !important;
  opacity: 0.54;
}
```

I'm sure you've noticed the `input::-moz-placeholder` (?) and the `textarea` is *also* part of the fun. But did you notice *this*?

```
textarea > .anonymous-div,
input > .anonymous-div,
```

`.anonymous-div`? What the heck is that? Whatever it is, the selector indicates it's within the `input/textarea` element. Really?

Later, the unusual truth comes out:

```
 /*
  * Make form controls inherit 'unicode-bidi' transparently as required by
  *  their various anonymous descendants and pseudo-elements:
  *
  * <textarea> and <input type="text">:
  *  inherit into the XULScroll frame with class 'anonymous-div' which is a
  *  child of the text control.
  *
  * Buttons (either <button>, <input type="submit">, <input type="button">
  *          or <input type="reset">)
  *  inherit into the ':-moz-button-content' pseudo-element.
  *
  * <select>:
  *  inherit into the ':-moz-display-comboboxcontrol-frame' pseudo-element and
  *  the <optgroup>'s ':before' pseudo-element, which is where the label of
  *  the <optgroup> gets displayed. The <option>s don't use anonymous boxes,
  *  so they need no special rules.
  */
textarea > .anonymous-div,
input > .anonymous-div,
input::-moz-placeholder,
textarea::-moz-placeholder,
*|*::-moz-button-content,
*|*::-moz-display-comboboxcontrol-frame,
optgroup:before {
  unicode-bidi: inherit;
  text-overflow: inherit;
}
```

So there you go. There's an "anonymous" (`div`) embedded within all `textarea` and `input[type=text]` elements you work with. Here's some XUL that seems [plausibly similar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/Adding_Methods_to_XBL-defined_Elements?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=XUL_Tutorial/Adding_Methods_to_XBL-defined_Elements) to what is probably going on right under our noses:

**XUL**

```
<box id="num" class="labeledbutton" title="Number of Things:" value="52"/>

<button label="Show" oncommand="document.getElementById('num').showTitle(true)"/>
<button label="Hide" oncommand="document.getElementById('num').showTitle(false)"/>
```

**XBL**

```
<binding id="labeledbutton">
  <content>
    <xul:label xbl:inherits="value=title"/>
    <xul:label xbl:inherits="value"/>
  </content>
  <implementation>
    <method name="showTitle">
      <parameter name="state"/>
      <body>
        if (state) document.getAnonymousNodes(this)[0].
          setAttribute("style","visibility: visible");
        else document.getAnonymousNodes(this)[0].
          setAttribute("style","visibility: collapse");
      </body>
    </method>
  </implementation>
</binding>
```

Unfortunately, the manner in which Firefox deals with this "anonymous" gang of pseudo-elements means you probably won't be able to manipulate the `placeholder`'s text like we did in Chrome.

And just now I found the XUL/XBL markup that includes the `input` and `placeholder` mechanism/definition. Here it is:

```
  <property name="label" onset="this.setAttribute('label', val); return val;"
                         onget="return this.getAttribute('label') ||
                                        (this.labelElement ? this.labelElement.value :
                                         this.placeholder);"/>
  <property name="placeholder" onset="this.inputField.placeholder = val; return val;"
                               onget="return this.inputField.placeholder;"/>
  <property name="emptyText" onset="this.placeholder = val; return val;"
                             onget="return this.placeholder;"/>
```

Which handles the `placeholder` swapping. The following shows in the `.anonymous-div`, which appears to get swapped out with some code from the core. I'll spare you those gory details.

```
  <binding id="input-box">
    <content context="_child">
      <children/>
      ...
    </content>
```

These last two blocks I found within:

```
jar:file:///C:/path/to/a/FirefoxPortable/App/firefox/omni.ja!/chrome/toolkit/content/global/bindings/textbox.xml
```

If you're interested in getting into Firefox's business on this (or in general), try this if you're interesting in getting into more of the actual chrome HTML and CSS files:

*resource://gre-resources/*

You can read more on [`::-webkit-input-placeholder` or `::-moz-placeholder` in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css/2610741#2610741). Take note that this particular type of selector (*pseudo-element*, *not pseudo class*... at least *lately*...) is somewhat brittle in the way you approach using them in stylesheets.

http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/layout/style/forms.css.html

Phew. Never thought this snipe hunt was going to end. Hope that helps somebody. I learned some things, like the context menu over the `input[type=text]` elements is *hardcoded* into the XUL code with the element markup definition. Another surprise.

Anyhow, good luck.

Comment: TL;DR but you have my vote all the same. Looks like you've been deep in the belly of the beast. This vendor specific stuff is so fleeting and limited in use, it's hard for me to be genuinely interested. Chrome especially is a strange animal sometimes.

Comment: @Jared Farrish .. Great work for digging in deep, but at the moment this looks greek to me . :) .. I will try to dig in and research the info that you have provided .. Thanks

Comment: @mog - I cleaned the opening up and indicate where the answer ends and the "extended details" begin. Yeah, I've had a [peculiar fascination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450755/save-source-of-popup-window-as-string/12454721#12454721) with getting inside the browser once I figured out I could. I probably also have a little bit of interest that I won't go into. I find it interesting, at least. Also, Mog?

Comment: @Sushanth-- - I made the answer more clear (it only works on webkit browsers). The rest is *why* it doesn't work on Firefox, plus some other things I discovered while researching it. HTH.

Comment: @Sushanth-- - This fiddle is fairly close to how Firefox (and I believe Chrome) handles an `input` (and `textarea`): http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/3AdD7/ The `#textbox` would be the `input`, the inner elements the hidden parts of the `input`. Note, only tested in Chrome and not (really) production ready in any way. Just a demo.

Answer (score 2):

Using only CSS it is not possible to do this literally. Your attempt is a bit off too, `placeholder` is not an element but rather an attribute, and the `content` property is only used with `:before` and `:after` properties, which `input` does not support. (also you have a mistake in your spelling `placehodler`)

The best approach would be to change it in the markup, or if that's not possible, with javascript:

```
yourElementSelector.placeholder = 'Search by name';
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the finer points that I have missed.. Currently I am using javascript to get the things done. So was wondering if there was a way out by using plain `CSS` . That hack you tried was really good one. But ..

Comment: Well... @Sushanth--, *placeholder is not an element but an attribute* is, unbelievably, *inaccurate*. Maybe it works different than we think it would or should. It turns out that yes, **`::-moz-placeholder` is a `DIV`** within an `input`. And there's possibly *another* element *within* that seemingly untouchable (in Firefox) `.anonymous-div` low-level container for `placeholder`. In Chrome, it seems `:before` and `:after` may actually append new nodes to the pseudo-element `::-webkit-input-placeholder`. So Wesley's "goofy" fiddle is more literal than we guessed. I'll write it up.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I get what you're saying, but it's technically accurate. A browser may *generate* an element, but `placeholder` itself is not an HTML element. The reason I said it in the first place is because I read the OP's LESS/SASS code wrong, it's actually using `input:placeholder` and not `input placeholder` as I thought. In any case, CSS is not the best way to change placeholder text, but it appears it *can* be done.

Comment: I posted the results of my unfortunately somewhat exhaustive research. It's a bit different that I thought beneath ol' Firefox's hood. Short answer: An input is a nested series of HTML and XUL elements.

Answer (score -1):

No. Can you imagine changing the value of a field using CSS ?

What you expect, is same as this. You should use javascript.

Comment: Is that a rhetorical question?